# PHP - Extract Custom Operators from String

Tags: php

I have a MySQL database back-end which is searched via PHP. I'm trying to implement custom operators for detailed searching.
Here is an example:

```
$string = "o:draw t:spell card";
```

Where `o:` = Search by Description and `t:` = Card Typing. This would be similar to a custom syntax from a site like Scryfall https://scryfall.com/docs/syntax

Here is my work in progress example for `o:`

```
$string = "o:draw t:spell card";

    if (strpos($string, 'o:') !== false) {
        $text = explode('o:', $string, 2)[1];
        echo $text;
    }
```

The output is: `draw t:spell card`

I'm trying to get the output to respond with just: `draw`

However, it would also need to be able to accomplish this   "smartly". It may not always be in a specific order and may show up alongside other operators.

Any suggestions on how to build around a system like this in PHP?

Example user searches:

**Search Description + Type (new Syntax):**

```
o:draw a card t:spell card
```

**Search Card Name/Description (what it currently does):**

```
Time Wizard
```

**Search Card Name/Description (what it currently does):**

```
Draw a Card
```

**Combination of new and old syntax:**

```
Time Wizard t:effect monster
```

Comment: Does after `:` follows only one word? Can it be `o:draw card from stack` as one token?

Comment: Unfortunately no. It could be o:special summon or o:send to the graveyard. I'm thinking it will need to get all text before the next operator if any?

Comment: Just to clarify: you saw that there is an API for scryfall? https://scryfall.com/docs/api

Comment: Yep I know! However I am trying to implement this on top of my own database which is Yu-Gi-Oh! based which currently only really has filter searching. https://db.ygoprodeck.com/search/

Comment: So you control the database? It would make your life so much easier if you stored the description and type in separate columns. They could then be indexed for faster searching.

Comment: `preg_match_all("/(?:([ot]):)?(\w+)/", …)` for starters

Comment: Sorry, they are in separate columns! But what I am trying to accomplish is having custom operators tell the database what to search by having them type it. So a user types o:draw t:spell card" and it searches "where description like ''%draw% and type = 'Spell Card'". The issue here however is trying to extract what they have typed exactly in php

Comment: Well I see that you need to search for custom parser or have all possible prefixes. Because from your documentation I see that it's possible to have non `:` syntax. E.g. `m>3w` `cmc=5`, etc. https://scryfall.com/docs/syntax#mana

Comment: Sorry just to clarify, that's not my documentation and I'm not trying to replicate everything they have since it's not necessary (I'm doing this for a different tcg game). So I'm starting light and only doing a handful of operators: "o:", "t:", "atk:", "def:", "l:"

Comment: Why would you make the user type all that? What's wrong with separate inputs for description and type?

Comment: It's been a frequently requested addition! You'd be surprised how many people want it. It's an addition on top of all the filters we currently have (which lets you search description/type).

Comment: Alright. I believe there is a definite list of these operators, am I right about that? And this search filter, it would contain nothing but those operators and their values?

Comment: Unfortunately the search filter could contain the card name too. So the idea is that they can directly search by the card name or additionally use the operators

Comment: So the card name has no operator? And could be positioned anywhere in the string?

Comment: Yes unfortunately. As it stands, it's a simple input box that takes whatever the user types and does "SELECT * FROM DB WHERE NAME  = ? OR DESCRIPTION = ?"

Comment: Without restricting the position of "old" name/description to the beginning of the search, I don't see how this can be pulled off. If it can be anywhere, then you'd need some sort of delimiter to indicate where the operator values stop and the "regular" input begins and vice versa.

Comment: I agree with El_V, @GenesisBits. This question is poorly defined and the bounty is going to attract low-quality answers that will simply try to give it a punt.  Please overhaul your question, to provide a sufficient sample of inputs (like 10 or 20 of them) and your exact expected result.  You need to identify (in your sample inputs) all of the fringe cases that need to be satisfied.  We want to see mixed syntax, reordered syntax, and anything else that may cause trouble.

Comment: @GenesisBits Is this the behavior that you are expecting? https://3v4l.org/vlp1Q

Comment: @GenesisBits Alternatively, this does the same: https://3v4l.org/CrEYO  How do you actually need this data to be prepared for your query?  What other fringe cases must be accommodated?

Comment: Hi mickmackusa, that behavior is definitely what I am expecting! I think that will do what I need actually. Please feel free to set it as an answer.

Comment: I'd just like to point out that the code provided by @mickmackusa is suitable only for single character operators (would have to be modified for "atk" or "def" for example). You should really update the question with full requirements and more examples if you want a complete answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am unable to take your input all the way through to sql strings, because I don't know if you have more columns to access than the two that you have listed in your question.

To begin to script a parser for your users' input, you will need to understand all of the possible inputs that you wish to accommodate and assign specific handlers for each occurrence.  This task has the ability to turn into a rabbit hole -- in other words, it may become an ever-extending and diverging task.  My answer is only to get you started; I'm not in it for the long haul.

1. Declare a whitelist of commands that you intend to respect.  In my snippet, this is `$commands`.  The whitelist of strings with special meaning must not be confused with any card name strings -- I have added the best fringe case that I can find in the YuGiOh database (a card name containing a colon).
2. Build a regex pattern using the whitelist to find qualifying delimiting spaces in input strings.
3. Iterate the array generated by the regex-split input and assess each element to determine if/how it will be integrated into the WHERE clause of your sql.
4. At this early stage, it is fair to only allow one card name per input string, but certainly possible that users will wish to enter multiple card types to filter their expected result set.

I am electing to sanitize the user input by trimming leading and trailing whitespace and converting all letters to lowercase.  I assume you will be running a modern database which will make case-insensitive comparisons.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/mIdhC))

```
$tests = [
    'o:draw a card t:spell card',
    'Time Wizard',
    'Draw a Card',
    'Time Wizard t:effect monster',
    'A-Team: Trap Disposal Unit',
    't: effect o: draw a card atk: 1400 def: 600 l: 4 t: fairy',
];

$commands = [
    'o'   => '',         // seems to be useless to me
    't'   => 'type',     // card type
    'atk' => 'attack',   // card's attack value
    'def' => 'defense',  // card's defense value
    'l'   => 'level',    // card's level value
];

$pattern = '~ *(?=(?:' . implode('|', array_keys($commands)) . '):)~';  // create regex pattern using commands lookup

foreach ($tests as $test) {
    foreach (preg_split($pattern, strtolower(trim($test)), 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY) as $component) {
        $colectomy = explode(':', $component, 2);
        if (count($colectomy) < 2) {
            if ($colectomy[0] !== 'draw a card') {  // "draw a card" seems worthless to the query
                $result[$test]['cardName (old syntax)'] = $component;
            }
        } elseif ($colectomy[0] !== 'o') {  // o command seems worthless to the query
            if (isset($commands[$colectomy[0]])) {
                $result[$test][$commands[$colectomy[0]]][] = $colectomy[1];  // enable capturing of multiple values of same command
            } else {
                $result[$test]['cardName (new syntax)'] = $component;
            }
        }
    }
}

var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'o:draw a card t:spell card' => 
  array (
    'type' => 
    array (
      0 => 'spell card',
    ),
  ),
  'Time Wizard' => 
  array (
    'cardName (old syntax)' => 'time wizard',
  ),
  'Time Wizard t:effect monster' => 
  array (
    'cardName (old syntax)' => 'time wizard',
    'type' => 
    array (
      0 => 'effect monster',
    ),
  ),
  'A-Team: Trap Disposal Unit' => 
  array (
    'cardName (new syntax)' => 'a-team: trap disposal unit',
  ),
  't: effect o: draw a card atk: 1400 def: 600 l: 4 t: fairy' => 
  array (
    'type' => 
    array (
      0 => ' effect',
      1 => ' fairy',
    ),
    'attack' => 
    array (
      0 => ' 1400',
    ),
    'defense' => 
    array (
      0 => ' 600',
    ),
    'level' => 
    array (
      0 => ' 4',
    ),
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can so something like below to extract key value from string.

```
$tags = ['o:', 't:'];

$str = "t:spell card o:draw a card";

$dataList = [];
foreach($tags as $tag){
    $tagDataLevel1 = explode($tag, $str, 2)[1];
    $expNew = explode(':', $tagDataLevel1,2);
    if(count($expNew)==2){
        $tagData= strrev(explode(' ',strrev($expNew[0]),2)[1]);
    }else{
        $tagData = $tagDataLevel1;
    }

    $dataList[$tag] = $tagData;
   //overwrite string
    $str = str_replace($tag . $tagData,"",$str);

}

$oldKeyWord = $str;

var_dump ($dataList);
echo $oldKeyWord;
```

Comment: This answer is missing its explanation.